# In the ggdid function in R, how can one remove error bars?

Tags: r, charts, graphics, economics, causal-inference

I have the following R code to create a dynamic plot of the differences in my differences estimation (es):

```
ggdid(es,
            xgap = 13, 
            theme = FALSE, ref_line = 0, se = FALSE) + 
        xlim(-30, 30) +
        ylim(-1.1, 1.1) +
        geom_point(size = 3, color = "black") +
        geom_hline(yintercept = 0) +
        geom_vline(xintercept = 0))
```

My problems are that I need to:

1. remove the confidence intervals
2. put a vertical bar at the 0 mark on the x-axis.

Comment: Please provide a [minimal, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).